# Here is a short bit of Latex code that keeps crashing. Why?

Tags: etoolbox

```
\documentclass[12pt]{leter}
\usepackage[paperwidth=2.25in, paperheight=4in, margin=1mm, textwidth=1.85in]{geometry} % Define paper stock size here
\special{papersize=2in,3.75in}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[code=Code39,X=.275mm,ratio=2.25,H=.5cm]{makebarcode}
\newcommand\finline[3][]{\begin{myfont}[#1]{#2}#3\end{myfont}}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\PrintOne}[2]
{
  \isblank{#2}{#1}{#2}
}

\pdfpagewidth 2.5in



\vspace{2mm}
{\Large \textbf{bin}}
\hfill
{\Large \textbf{number}}

\vspace{2mm}
\hline
\vspace{2mm}

\centerline{\barcode{number}}

\\

{\Large \centerline{\testbf{ABC-Store}} \par}

\\

{\tiny \centerline {\textbf{DIGITAL OFFICE SOLUTIONS}} \par}}
\vspace{2mm}
\hline
\PrintOne{description}{itemnotes}

\\

\small{description}

\\
Please email -------@----------.com 24 hours a day or Call 204-555-1212 between 8:00am 4:00pm to reorder. Please reference the Bio-Static serial number from the yellow label on your copier.  
\\
\newpage


\end{document}
```

What it does is print a 2.25x4 label with a bar code, and then I want it to print one of the two variables in the `\PrintOne` function.  for some reason all it does it crash with an error from the calling program.  If I take out the `\usepackage{etoolbox}`  and the `\PrintOne` everything prints.   But it prints too much, I only want one of the `\PrintOne` to print.

Comment: `leter` class? Do you mean `letter`? Sorry, this document seems to be a mess. There's a stray `\hline` without `tabular` environment which breaks the code already

Comment: why are you using geometry but the setting page size with dvips special?

Comment: If I fix `leter` to `letter` the document stops with an error on `\hline` (which is only valid in tables) but that error seems to be unrelated to the problem you describe. Please fix the example so that it does not have unrelated errors to give people  a chance to see the intended problem.

Comment: `\ifblank`, not `\isblank`

Comment: By the way, here is a question from you with answers, but you never accepted one of them: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224272/how-do-i-print-out-dates-in-yyyy-mmm-dd-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please no comments on the spacing here (that's not my issue here)

The main errors were

- `leter` instead of `letter`
- `\hline` without `tabular` environment
- `\isblank` instead of `\ifblank`
- `\testbf` instead of `\textbf`
- Stray `}` at some places

It compiles now, but I have no idea what the result should be.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[paperwidth=2.25in, paperheight=4in, margin=1mm, textwidth=1.85in]{geometry} % Define paper stock size here
%\special{papersize=2in,3.75in}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[code=Code39,X=.275mm,ratio=2.25,H=.5cm]{makebarcode}
\newcommand\finline[3][]{\begin{myfont}[#1]{#2}#3\end{myfont}}
\usepackage{times}

\newcommand{\PrintOne}[2]
{
  \ifblank{#2}{#1}{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\pdfpagewidth 2.5in



\vspace{2mm}
{\Large \textbf{bin}}
\hfill
{\Large \textbf{number}}

\vspace{2mm}
%\hline
\vspace{2mm}

\centerline{\barcode{42}}


{\Large \centerline{\textbf{ABC-Store}} \par}


{\tiny \centerline {\textbf{DIGITAL OFFICE SOLUTIONS}} \par}
\vspace{2mm}
%\hline
\PrintOne{description}{itemnotes}


\small{description}


Please email -------@----------.com 24 hours a day or Call 204-555-1212 between 8:00am 4:00pm to reorder. Please reference the Bio-Static serial number from the yellow label on your copier.  


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are spurious spaces -- I leave them to the OP as an exercise ;-)

Comment: Got the barcode label to work!!!!   YEA!!!!!!!
Question how to I get the \tabular to work?
\begin{tabularx}{19cm}{C{5mm} L{2.1cm} L{8.5cm} C{1cm} C{7mm} R{1.5cm} R{1.5cm} }
  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Notes} & \textbf{Qt'y} &
    \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Price} & \textbf{Amount}  \\ [0.5em]
<%foreach number%>
  <%runningnumber%> & <%number%> & <%description%> & <%qty%> & <%unit%> & <%sellprice%> & <%linetotal%>  \\
<%end number%>
\end{tabularx}
Where <%description%>  is I would like it to print \PrintOne of the variables itemnotes, and description.

Comment: @GregoryWest: Yes, the answer is always `42` ;-)

Comment: @GregoryWest: Your editing your question away from your original post. There was no table in your OP

Comment: Both examples are being passed data from the calling program.  interestingly enough almost the exact same data-set in both cases. The working example was made simpler because of a glitch with cut/paste.  but the two sets of code are almost the same.   One prints invoices, one prints barcode labels.

Comment: @Gregory: You should reconsider/reprogram the calling program. There are a lot of issues

Comment: Unfortunatly the calling program is not mine.  I am trying to fix a report.

Comment: i copied your code into the report, instead of getting "itemnotes" after the line with "Digital Office Solutions"   I am getting "itemnotesdescriptionitemnotes"   Why would that be happening?   Could there be something very off with the version of Latex I am using?

Comment: Unless you don't have a stone age LaTeX (say TeXLive 2009 etc.) I would say: No. My code would compile with TL 2013/2014/2015, I would say ... edit: Just checked with TL 2015: Same result as in the posted screen shot