# Putting a \newcommand in a tabularx

Tags: macros, tabularx

I have two command I have created with `\newcommand`, both work find.  One is `\mydate{date_variable}`  the other is `\PrintOne{Variable1}{Variable2}`.  My problem is I can not figure out how I can put them in two of my columns in a `tabularx` table.

The TeX report is begin called from a program that is not mine so I do not have any way of changing it.  I do know the data being passed to it, and can print everything I need, just not in a `tabularx` :(

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should show an example of the tabular and where the commands should appear/do something. A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: This question seems to be a follow-up of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248403/here-is-a-short-bit-of-latex-code-that-keeps-crashing-why/248407#248407

Comment: ` \begin{tabularx}{19cm}{C{5mm} L{1.5cm} L{4.5cm} L{5cm} C{1cm} C{1cm} R{1.25cm} R{1.25cm} }
`  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Notes} & \textbf{Qt'y} &
`    \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Price} & \textbf{Amount}  \\ [0.5em]
`<%foreach number%>
`  <%runningnumber%> & <%number%> & <%description%> & <%itemnotes%>
`  & <%qty%> & <%unit%> & <%sellprice%> & <%linetotal%>  \\
`<%end number%>
`\end{tabularx}
`  Think this is what you were looking for.   As before, yes I need to be able to print %description% only if %itemnotes% is blank, otherwise print %itemnotes%.

Comment: Column widths are not an issue as they are static. Again, I do not have any control over the calling program.  I am trying to fix a report that is being printed.

Answer (score 2):

The body of `tabularx` is executed multiple times, to find the best column widths, so `\newcommand` doesn't work as it generates an error on the second trial.

Use `\newcommand\mycommand{}` before the table to  initialise then you can use `\renewcommand\mycommand{..}` within the `tabularx`.

Comment: Or the non-LaTeX way of using `\def`, for me it's like the local version of `\newcommand` (altough I know `\newcommand` is not `\global`).

Comment: @Manuel if you do that you are not warned if you over-write a command `\def\count{...}` would be bad for example. Doing it as above you would get an error for that.

Comment: Yes, I know. I wrote the comment to say what's the most common way of dealing with that, of course, *at your own risk*.

Comment: I tried putting {\ifblank{<%itemnotes%>}{<%description%>}{<%itemnotes%>}}    But what is happening is I am getting Itemnotes, printed twice, with description in the middle...    ARGH

Comment: @GregoryWest it is impossible to guess from fragments in comments what you did.  Please edit the question to have a _complete_  small document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that reproduces the error. Add it to the question and mark as a code block using `{}` in the editor.

Comment: %%  MAIN DETAIL LINE
\begin{tabularx}{19cm}{C{5mm} L{2.1cm} L{8.5cm} C{1cm} C{7mm} R{1.5cm} R{1.5cm} }
%%\begin{tabularx}{19cm}{p{5mm} l l l c c r r c c c}
  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Description / Notes} & \textbf{Qt'y} &
    \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Price} & \textbf{Amount}  \\ [0.5em]
<%foreach number%>
  <%runningnumber%> & <%number%>
    & {\ifblank{<%itemnotes%>}{<%description%>}{<%itemnotes%>}}
    & <%qty%> & <%unit%> & <%sellprice%> & <%linetotal%>  \\
\\
<%end number%>
\end{tabularx}

Here is the section in question.  the whole document is rather long to post here.

Comment: @GregoryWest no sorry as I said it is impossible to tell what you did from  fragments in comments.

Comment: @GregoryWest in particular I can't even guess what you mean by `<%foreach number%> ` which doesn't appear to be tex at all.

Comment: Understood.   This is a report from a web based program.   The Tex is being passed a bunch of arrays of line information.   The %for each% causes each line item to be printer out on the report.   There are two fields, %itemnotes% and %description%.    Basically I need Description printer out, UNLESS there is something in %itemnotes% then it supersedes %description%.     I would have thought this would be a straight forward thing to do, obviously I was mistaken...

Comment: @GregoryWest The report generator is completely off topic. You can add to your question a sample generated report that is a complete tex document, and ask about that.